# Adding a company logo to the Resume?

Tags: cv, logos

I want to add a logo to my Resume as well, I have two questions regarding that,

1. What is the dimension I need to create the logo for my Resume? I tried to see if font awesome provides any package for the list of companies I have in my Resume, there is none. How can I create the logo in the first place?
2. This is my tex file, how can I add a company logo corresponding to my work experience. [Resume.tex][2]

[image: Resume in PDF]
Ideally, I would like to swap the bullet point wit the logo and remove the name of the company or Is there an easier place to put the logo?

Update 1:

This is the best I could get to, Still am not able to get replace the bullet point with the image.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%-----------------------------------------------------------

\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{0.80}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{6,108,170}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,urlcolor=myblue}
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Adjust margins to 0.5in on all sides
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.0in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Custom commands

\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt}}
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{{\large \colorbox{mygrey}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}{\textbf{#1 \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}\end{minipage}}}}
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{
\begin{tabular*}{7.0in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-6pt}}
\newcommand{\envitem}[1]{\item #1}
\newcommand{\resenvsubheading}[6]{
\begin{tabular*}{7.0in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        #6 \textbf{#1}  & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
        \textbf{#5}
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-6pt}}

\makeatletter
\DeclareUrlCommand\ULurl@@{%
  \def\UrlFont{\ttfamily\color{blue}}%
  \def\UrlLeft{\bgroup}%
  \def\UrlRight{\egroup}}
\def\ULurl@#1{\hyper@linkurl{\ULurl@@{#1}}{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\ULurl{\hyper@normalise\ULurl@}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\resheading{Work Experience}
    \resenvsubheading{ \ULurl{http://www.oracle.com}}{Redwood City, CA}{Senior Software Engineer}{May 2015 - Present}
    {Environment: Openstack, Docker, Swift, Nimbula, Jenkins, Python, REST}{\adjustbox{valign=c}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{logo.png}}}
    \begin{itemize}
        \resitem{Designed and coded the Oracle Cloud Machine(OCM) openstack nova driver, VNC console proxy via SSH tunnel in Python using Parakmiko.}
        \resitem{Built the CLI, installer and deployment tools using click, jinja2, fabric Python modules for deploying OCM Openstack and Openstack Swift Storage for the production environment.}
        \resitem{Built Openstack Swift Storage installer as a Linux RPM.}
        \resitem{Rapid Prototyping of Openstack using devstack and Swift using Vagrant on Oracle Linux 7.}
        \resitem{Designed the architecture of the microservices for Swift Object Storage.}  
        \resitem{Built the container orchestration for Swift Object Storage using Docker containers on Oracle Linux 7 for OCM in Python.}
        \resitem{Built a HA solution for Swift Object Storage using HAProxy with SSL termination.}
        \resitem{Built Jenkins jobs in bash for CI/CD of Exalogic Openstack and Openstack Swift Storage.}
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Ideally I would want to have the all three lines covering the width of the logo. How can I achieve this?[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "dimension" of the logo? It seems to me all you need is to find the logo online somewhere, download it, and throw it in with `\includegraphics`, adjusting the size as necessary (as the question you've linked does).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean, exactly. But maybe something like this:

```
% attempting to minimally change how your original input was used...
\newlength\resimgwd
\newlength\tabimgwd
\renewcommand{\resenvsubheading}[6]{%
  \par
  \adjustimage{valign=m, max totalheight=3\baselineskip, gstore width=\resimgwd}{#6}%
  \setlength{\tabimgwd}{\dimexpr\textwidth - 1.25\resimgwd\relax}%
  \hfill
  \begin{tabular*}{\tabimgwd}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{}}
    \textbf{#1} & #2\\
    \textit{#3} & \textit{#4}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{#5}} \\
  \end{tabular*}
  \vspace{-6pt}}
```

I also recommend you redefine `\resheading` so you avoid overfull lines:

```
\renewcommand{\resheading}[1]{%
      \adjustbox{left, margin=1ex, width={\textwidth}, bgcolor=mygrey}{\bfseries #1}}
```

Complete file:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
%\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%-----------------------------------------------------------

\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{0.80}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{6,108,170}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,urlcolor=myblue}
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% NOTE: Don't do it this way: use a dedicated package, like geometry.sty
% Adjust margins to 0.5in on all sides
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.0in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Custom commands

\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt}}
% This command will produce overfull lines
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{{%
    \par\large
    \fboxsep 0pt%
    \colorbox{mygrey}{%
      \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
          \textbf{#1}
      \end{minipage}
    }%
  }}

\renewcommand{\resheading}[1]{%
  \adjustbox{left, margin=1ex, width={\textwidth}, bgcolor=mygrey}{\bfseries #1}}

\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{
\begin{tabular*}{7.0in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-6pt}}

\newcommand{\envitem}[1]{\item #1}

\newcommand{\resenvsubheading}[6]{
\begin{tabular*}{7.0in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        #6 \textbf{#1}  & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
        \textbf{#5}
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-6pt}}

\newlength\resimgwd
\newlength\tabimgwd
\renewcommand{\resenvsubheading}[6]{%
  \par
  \adjustimage{valign=m, max totalheight=3\baselineskip, gstore width=\resimgwd}{#6}%
  \setlength{\tabimgwd}{\dimexpr\textwidth - 1.25\resimgwd\relax}%
  \hfill
  \begin{tabular*}{\tabimgwd}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{}}
    \textbf{#1} & #2\\
    \textit{#3} & \textit{#4}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{#5}} \\
  \end{tabular*}
  \vspace{-6pt}}


\makeatletter
\DeclareUrlCommand\ULurl@@{%
  \def\UrlFont{\ttfamily\color{blue}}%
  \def\UrlLeft{\bgroup}%
  \def\UrlRight{\egroup}}
\def\ULurl@#1{\hyper@linkurl{\ULurl@@{#1}}{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\ULurl{\hyper@normalise\ULurl@}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\resheading{Work Experience}%
\resenvsubheading
{\ULurl{http://www.oracle.com}}%
{Redwood City, CA}%
{Senior Software Engineer}%
{May 2015 - Present}%
{Environment: Openstack, Docker, Swift, Nimbula, Jenkins, Python,
  REST}%
%{\adjustbox{valign=c}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{000.png}}}
{000.png}

    \begin{itemize}
      \resitem{Designed and coded the Oracle Cloud Machine(OCM)
        openstack nova driver, VNC console proxy via SSH tunnel in
        Python using Parakmiko.}

      \resitem{Built the CLI, installer and deployment tools using
        click, jinja2, fabric Python modules for deploying OCM
        Openstack and Openstack Swift Storage for the production
        environment.}

      \resitem{Built Openstack Swift Storage installer as a Linux
        RPM.}

      \resitem{Rapid Prototyping of Openstack using devstack and Swift
        using Vagrant on Oracle Linux 7.}

      \resitem{Designed the architecture of the microservices for
        Swift Object Storage.}

      \resitem{Built the container orchestration for Swift Object
        Storage using Docker containers on Oracle Linux 7 for OCM in
        Python.}

      \resitem{Built a HA solution for Swift Object Storage using
        HAProxy with SSL termination.}

      \resitem{Built Jenkins jobs in bash for CI/CD of Exalogic
        Openstack and Openstack Swift Storage.}
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: add logo to resume image]

Comment: This is kind of where I expect the image to be placed, but I don't want the borders around. Is there a way to avoid the borders ?

Comment: What borders? That's maybe just from using the `showframe` option of the `geometry` package. I added that option only to make it clear where various things were being placed relative to the margins of the typeblock.

Comment: I get this when i run your code                                                              ! File ended while scanning use of \@argdef.
<inserted text>
\par
<*> test.tex
?
! Emergency stop.
<inserted text>
\par
<*> test.tex
End of file on the terminal!

Comment: @Arman -- There was a missing closing brace (`}`)  in line 41. I changed it now so the line reads `\textbf{#1}`. Does that fix the problem? (As you didn't give the line number related to the error, I can't be sure.)